# Mongo Query - Return docs if data is 0 or null

Tags: mongodb

I have data in the following format:

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("12367687"),
    "xyzId" : "ADV_ID",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-08-19T10:58:21.473Z"),
    "gId" : "987654",
    "type" : "checks"
}
```

For the above data i have to plot a graph for daily, weekly, monthly and yearly data using the "created_on" field and count for "type" field. I have the following query which works partially.

```
     db.trackads.aggregate(
     {$match : {"gId" : "987654",type : 'checks'}},
     { $group : { _id : { "day" : {"$week" : "$date"}},cnt : {"$sum" : 1}}});
```

Result:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : 34
            },
            "cnt" : 734
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "day" : 33
            },
            "cnt" : 349
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But with the above query, i do not get results of dates(week no ) when count for "type" = impressions is 0. How should i modify the mongo query to get the results for count 0 ???

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you can do it as follows.

```
db.trackads.aggregate({$match:{"groupId":"520a077c62d4b3b00e008905",$or:[{type:{$exists:false}},{type:'impressions'}]}},{$group:{_id:{"day":{"$week":"$created_on"}},cnt:{"$sum":1}}});
```

Comment: was this answer meant to go with a different question?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be to add the zeroes in the code that consumes the results of this query.

MongoDB can't invent data that is not there.  For example, how far back in time and forward in time would you expect it to go creating zeroes?